# Rails 2.3 Four Level Nested Form Javascript Function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, nested-forms

I'm using Alloy's Complex Form Example found [here](http://github.com/alloy/complex-form-examples/tree/master).  The example he provides is a two level hierarchy and I'm trying to expand it to four.

He has javascript functions for adding nested items.  How to expand for four nested layers?

```
'.add_nested_item': function(e){
   el = Event.findElement(e);
   template = eval(el.href.replace(/.*#/, ''))
   $(el.rel).insert({    
     bottom: replace_ids(template)
   });
 },
 '.add_nested_item_lvl2': function(e){
   el = Event.findElement(e);
   elements = el.rel.match(/(\w+)/g)
   parent = '.'+elements[0]
   child = '.'+elements[1]

   child_container = el.up(parent).down(child)    
   parent_object_id = el.up(parent).down('input').name.match(/.*\[(\d+)\]/)[1]

   template = eval(el.href.replace(/.*#/, ''))

   template = template.replace(/(attributes[_\]\[]+)\d+/g, "$1"+parent_object_id)

   // console.log(template)
    child_container.insert({     
     bottom: replace_ids(template)
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ryan Bates has made this solution easy.  Works with Rails 3 with helmerj's comment :)

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

helmerj's comment:

For the latest Rails3.rc ONe has to modify a single line:

in "module ApplicationHelper"

link_to_function(name, "add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")")

which removes the not needed h() function. Otherwise works like charm.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a bit overloaded form if you need to handle three-level hierarchy. rethink your UI first.

Other than that - i don't think you need to build your associated objects in controller since example app builds them (if necessary) in views (app/views/projects/_form.erb):

`<% @project.build_author unless @project.author %>
   <% project_form.fields_for :author do |author_form| %>`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the app builds the objects.  I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this isn't really my area of expertise either…

Let me just state that I wouldn't use the example that's used in the complex-form-examples for so much nesting. Rather I'd build the required form inputs completely in JS with the regular DOM API. That should give you a much cleaner and leaner implementation and also better testable.

Cheers,
Eloy